# Перенос сайта yii на openserver

Tags: php, yii

перенес сайт на локальный хостинг openserver. подключил бд, пути.
Выходит такая ошибка

> Fatal error: Call to a member function asCMenuArray() on a non-object
>   in
>   D:\OpenServer\domains\azimut_dev\themes\utasan\views\layouts\main.php
>   on line 246

В самом файле ошибок нет

Строчки кода, куда он ругается

```
<?php    
    Yii::import('application.modules.store.models.StoreCategory');
    $items = StoreCategory::model()->findByPk(1)->asCMenuArray();
    if(isset($items['items']))
    {
        $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'catalog-menu', 'id'=>'nav'),
                'items'=>$items['items'])
        );
    }

?>
```

скрин бд[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раз появляется такое сообщение, значит в файле ошибка есть, все-таки. Проверяйте, является ли по указанной строчке переменная экземпляром нужного класса. `var_dump()` поможет в этом.

Comment: вот строчка на которую он ругается <?php    
      Yii::import('application.modules.store.models.StoreCategory');
      $items = StoreCategory::model()->findByPk(1)->asCMenuArray();
               if(isset($items['items']))
      {
       $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
         'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'catalog-menu', 'id'=>'nav'),
         'items'=>$items['items'])
       );
      }
      
              ?>

Comment: Эту информацию нужно добавить в сам вопрос

Comment: какая версия PHP была там откуда вы перенесли, и какая версия стоит локально?

Comment: версия 5.5 и там и тут

Comment: Могут быть переопределены методы в StoreCategory, отвечающие за поиск (findByPk, beforeFind, afterFind). Или явно прописано подключение к другой бд.

Answer (score 1):

> $items = StoreCategory::model()->findByPk(1)->asCMenuArray();

В этой строчке кода вы никак не проверяете, было ли что либо найдено в таблице по вашему запросу. Может быть, записи с `ID = 1` нет, тогда метод `findByPk()` вернет `NULL` и возникнет указанная вами ошибка.

`NULL` — это не объект и метода `asCMenuArray()` у него нет. Вывод: проверяйте содержимое базы данных.

---

Автор вопроса уточнил, что проблема была в файле `main.php`.
В `savePath` использовалось старое значение с боевого сервера.